# BCP is failing with weird characters in column value

Tags: sql, sql-server

We are trying to export a BCP file to our SQL server table but it is constantly failing in some rows. One common problem we saw with the rows was they have weird characters in them. Example below:

This is the BCP (out of OP's comment below):

```
bcp risk_models.nis.EE_CSV_48 in {} -c -k -q -S sqlserver -U username -P password -h TABLOCK -b 500
```

And this is the weird output

```
  SAMPLE ROW 1 ▒
  SAMPLE ROW 2 ▒
```

Now the character at the end is our suspect but this character is converted into ? during the bcp load. What's more weird is that if we just load these rows without the others( by others I mean the ones without the weird character), the load is successful even with the weird character.

Can someone shed some light on what's wrong?

Comment: What is your BCP command line?

Comment: bcp risk_models.nis.EE_CSV_48 in {} -c -k -q -S sqlserver -U username -P password -h TABLOCK -b 500

Comment: You could try adding `-C RAW`, this will prevent BCP from converting between codepages. See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190657(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Apparently this flag is not supported in our version of BCP. Anyways. We tried converting the file to UTF-8 and saw that the weird character was actually the pound sign. Is there a way to load the file in SQL server treating it as UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: If memory serves me right, UTF-8 is not supported, UTF-16 is though.

Comment: Check the format the file is in. If it's UTF-8, check this restriction in [bcp utility docu](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx): *SQL Server does not support code page 65001 (UTF-8 encoding)* (that's in the `-C codepage` section).